# Hide checkmo payment method if billing and shipping address are different

Tags: payment-methods, billing-address, hide

I would like to hide the checkmo payment method on checkout, if the billing and shipping address are not the same.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code**

Create file : app/code/Vendor/Extension/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="disable_payment" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\Paymentmethoddisable" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Create file : app/code/Vendor/Extension/Observer/Paymentmethoddisable.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class Paymentmethoddisable implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        if($observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="checkmo"){ 

           // write your condition here
           if( 'billingaddress' != 'shippingaddresss'){
            $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            $checkResult->setData('is_available', false); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but 'billingaddress' != 'shippingaddresss' does not work.

Comment: You can get the billing and shipping address from the current quote.  And write the condition according to your logic.